# Can't remove a folder - "Element not found"

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

Got a bit of a problem on my laptop (Windows 8.1); I recently deleted all music that I had stored under C:\Dokumente\Musik ("Dokumente" meaning "documents" in German). Within this directory, I had a couple of subfolders for my music; I wanted to delete the entire "Dokumente" folder.
However, after deleting it, the folder remained along with but one subfolder (D:\Dokumente\Musik\Amazon\Giles Lamb\ ...), which is empty. When I try to delete the subfolder or the "Dokumente" folder, it just says "Element not found". Restarting the computer did not help.

It's not really a problem, however it's annoying, any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the method I got from a site.

> Deleting the windows.old folder manually
>
> 1) Open an elevated command prompt
>
> Click start
>       Type: cmd
>       right-click it under programs
>       click Run As Administrator
>
> 2) Take ownership
>
> Change the directory to the "Giles Lamb\" folder (e.g. cd d:\Giles Lamb)
>       Type: takeown /F . /A /R /D Y > NUL
>
> 3) grant yourself permission
>
> Type: icacls . /grant:r Administrators:(F) /T /L /Q
>
> 4) Delete everything
>
> *Make sure you close any explorer or command windows that are looking at or inside the Giles Lamb folder (except for the command window you are using). If you don't, you will receive an error while performing this step.*
>
> Type: cd ..
>   
>    Type: rmdir /S /Q windows.old

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in linux a few times and the solution was to use rsync , so, I though maybe robocopy might do it too! This worked for me to be able to delete the contents of the `$windows.~bt` folder that upgrades in Windows 10 make.

Open an elevated command prompt

make a blank folder to "copy" eg:

```
c:
cd \
mkdir blankfolder
```

`cd` to the directory you can't delete, eg:

```
cd $widnows.~bt
```

Run `icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET`

Run `takeown /R /F *`

Run `robocopy c:\blankfolder c:\$windows.~bt /mir`

The mirror option tells robocopy to mirror `c:\blankfolder` to `$windows.~bt` therefore deleting the files you don't want.

Usually you are supposed to use the diskcleanup wizard to remove these files, but, the drive that had this folder was in a `.wim` file, and the OS was not running.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

**Using a nifty third party utility**:

1. download [Unlocker](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) (this tool helps delete any folder/file by terminating the existing handles to the target)
2. open explorer (Win+E) and navigate to `D:\Dokumente\Musik\`
3. right click on `Amazon` folder and click `Unlocker`
4. select `delete` and click `OK` (terminate existing handles --if any)

**Using manual method:**

1. open `Command Prompt (elevated)` (Start > type `cmd` > right click and select `run as Administrator`)
2. close any unsaved work
3. type the following commands

a) `taskkill -im explorer.exe /f`

b) `cd < enter the path of the folder you want to delete here >` (ex: "cd D:\Dokumente\Musik")

c) `rd /s /q < folder name >`  (ex: rd /s /q "Amazon")

(Note: be careful while inputting the directory name)

Done. this should probably do it, the reason being.. all the handles from the explorer are possibly terminated (however, the handles from programs are not terminated).

Drop by for further assistance.